# AWS EKS Cluster : InvalidParameterException: Unsupported Kubernetes minor version update ,Gitlab CI, Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, kubernetes, cluster, terraform

The following errors occur every time I run the pipeline

```
│ Error: error updating EKS Cluster (business-staging) version: InvalidParameterException: Unsupported Kubernetes minor version update from 1.19 to 1.18
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "d3203e19-5691-48eb-9442-05435331c8a4"
│   },
│   ClusterName: "business-staging",
│   Message_: "Unsupported Kubernetes minor version update from 1.19 to 1.18"
│ }
│ 
│   with module.eks.aws_eks_cluster.this[0],
│   on .terraform/modules/eks/ekcluster.tf line 11, in resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this":
│    11: resource "aws_eks_cluster" "this" {
│ 
╵
```

what is the issue here , how to solve this, nay suggestion is appricated here .

Comment: https://rharshad.com/aws-eks-upgrade-1.18-to-1.19/ > *#4 The Kubernetes minor version of the nodes in your cluster must be the same as the version of your control plane’s current version before you update your control plane to a new Kubernetes version.*

Comment: Could you please describe a bit how to achieve this in terraform, aws Eks?

Comment: No, I can't. I merely pointed out some docs you may want to read in order to understand the error.